# C library for plotting DFA's, NFA's

Tags: c, plot, dfa, nfa

Any lightweight C libraries out there for plotting machines? I did a search but, all of the libraries I found are not task-specific, they are heavy. I need a lightweight library for plotting machines.

Answer (score 0):

How tightly integrated does it have to be in your code? How about printing some input which is processed by `graphviz`.

Comment: In fact, I'm writing a compiler for automata theory and I want to include a Octave-like command for plotting machines.